# Clicking 'Edit' on a good post review audit takes you to that page and then you can't finish the audit

Tags: bug, review, edits, review-audits

I clicked 'Edit' on a First Post review audit on Puzzling, because I wanted to add a tag. This took me away from the review queue, and so I had to go back in the history of the page to finish the review (because, you know, audits count towards badges :P). Can you fix this please?

The review can be found [here.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/22730)